# Google app engine cron job scheduling setup and pricing

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, cron

I want to trigger a https endpoint every 1 minute I was using cron-job.org but it is not that reliable and goes down often. I have looked at 2 options Microsoft azure scheduler and Google app engine cron scheduler. Microsoft scheduler [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/scheduler/) is very clear, however, I dont understand how to setup google [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?csw=1#The_Schedule_Format) and pricing to run the cron job every minute.

Answer (score 1):

To use Google's cron scheduler, you will have to pay for the app engine running 24x7. Whereas Azure Scheduler is a true microservice and you only pay based on number of jobs/job collections, not the underlying resources consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Microsoft's scheduler which appears to be an independently configurable and billable service, the GAE cron service can only be a part of a GAE app.

A standard environment GAE app is charged by instance-hours plus the various services it uses. See [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). But it also comes with fairly generous free daily [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas).

A simple app which would only make a few requests per minute - like the one you describe - should have no problems staying within the free daily limits.

Check the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart) to see how to get a basic app skeleton running. You already have the cron service doc, you only need the [`cron.yaml` Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cronref) to add a cron service to your app.